# How to set Unicode character as badge text on browser action in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, unicode, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I have just started developing a Chrome Extension, and I am almost done except for this one little problem.

I want to set a Unicode character as the badge text on a browser action, but what I've tried so far is **NOT** working.

Here's how it looks now.
[image]

- Unicode Character - **💩** (also known as 'poop')
- Its Unicode - U+1F4A9 (from [here](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/55/people/pile-of-poo))

What I tried till now:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '&#x1F4A9;'});   //shows '&#x1F4A9;'
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'U+1F4A9;'});    //shows 'Ú+1F4A9;'
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '\U1F4A9;'});    //shows '\U1F4A9;'
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '\\U1F4A9;'});   //shows '\\U1F4A9;'
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ''});          //shows empty box
```

What should I do so that it shows ?

**UPDATE** : As mentioned by @Xan in his answer and in a comment, that UI rendering cannot be controlled.

So, I tried doing this `<title></title>` to see whether Chrome can render that and can it show  in the tab heading.

Turned out that Chrome can.  [image]

So, Why can't Chrome render  in one place (browser Action) and can in another place (Tab heading or title bar) ?

Comment: Scroll down to "C/C++/Java Src" on your web page, and you'll see the correct escape sequence: `\uD83D\uDCA9`. If you see a box (that's what I see in Firefox and Chrome), then the font does not have the Pile of Poo glyph.

Comment: What OS are you trying this under? Do you have any better luck when you use a literal, say, 'я'?

Comment: @pvg I am trying this on Windows 8.1 OS - 64bit and the character `я` works fine but `` doesn't.

Comment: That is probably because 'я' or 'ya' is cyrillic and a single character, supported by pretty much any international font. Most emoji consist of two characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rob's comment shows, the last form is correct.

However, the font used for the badges simply does not have that Unicode character, and Chrome only ever uses 1 font for the badge, not looking for substitutions.

As such, you're out of luck.

Comment: Is there any way to include such a font in my Chrome extension which supports ``, like we do in regular web application?

Comment: No; you cannot specify which font is used for UI rendering.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla Why does the font matter? Shouldn't the font substitution algorithm fall back to using any font whatsoever for missing glyphs in the default one?

Comment: @tchrist In web content, yes. In Chrome's own UI elements, apparently not.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla \*shrug\* Chrome simply does _not_ do any substitutions for badges. There's a set font and that's it.

Comment: @Xan, Thank for everything. Seems like I will have to compromise. :(