# Chrome extension badge text - ✔ renders as âœ”

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, google-chrome-extension, text-rendering

I am trying to add a heavy check mark ([✔](http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%94)) to my Chrome extension’s badge text. When I update the badge from a background script, it works fine. When I update it from a script within the popup window, it renders as `âœ”`.

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
  text: '✔',
  tabId: tabId
});
```

Comment: have you tried it with the html code `&#10004;` rather than the character itself?

Comment: Yes. Then I literally get `&#10004;`.

Comment: It seems someone else had a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498506/how-to-set-unicode-character-as-badge-text-on-browser-action-in-chrome-extension

Comment: That’s a different problem. I know the check mark character can render properly because it works when I call it from the background script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The popup window is probably not defaulting to the correct character encoding.

You need to put `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head of your popup window.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this to fix encoding
`text: &#10004;`